# tarfile getmembers() very slow

Tags: python, performance, tarfile

Running

```
import tarfile
with tarfile.open(tgz, 'r:gz') as tar:
    members = tar.getmembers()
```

on a quite powerful Windows 10 machine with Python3.6.6.takes 15 minutes on a 250MB tgz with 2500 members.

Is there anything I can do to speed this up? Maybe, is there a non-standard library alternative? Maybe is this faster with later Python versions (I cannot use those here at work, but would be good to know nevertheless)?

My google search brought up this very old issue: https://bugs.python.org/issue11224

Maybe has there been a regression?

Comment: You might want to run it without the with statement, but I'm not sure if that will do much.                                               `tar = tarfile.open(tgz, 'r:gz')` `members = tar.getmembers()`

Comment: Unfortunately, a gzipped tar file has to be decompressed to extract even just the member names.  Depending on the contents, a 250 MB tar file could be over 2 GB of data when uncompressed.  What kind of disk(s) does your system have?  If you have to do 2 GB+ of IO to/from a slow 5,000 RPM SATA drive, it doesn't matter how powerful your CPUs are.

Comment: Good point, this was actually a network drive. Also, when I just checked performance on a local drive, both the local and the network drive were only a couple of seconds, so I suspect something was going on with the network.